# SSD: Samsung MZ-NTY2560 but with 512GB

Tags: ssd

Could you suggest a proper 512GB replacement for 256GB Samsung MZ-NTY2560 SSD (standart drive in Samsung Notebook 9 2017)?
All options I saw like Samsung 960 Pro make me uncertain about their interchangeability.
It's a bit expensive to make a mistake buying this piece, so please excuse my desire to get sure despite of Wikipedia articles about M.2.